# How do I prevent a dynamicMapLayer from refreshing on every zoom or pan of the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, arcgis, esri

I'm using the leaflet [`L.esri.dynamicMapLayer`](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html) to display a large amount of polylines on the map, and the export request to ArcGIS Server to draw them can take a while. If the user quickly makes several zooms or pans, I can end up with a bunch of pending export requests, which also blocks other requests to ArcGIS Server. All those export requests except the last are useless.

For other client side layers, I'm already controlling the refresh by making sure the user has stopped zooming or panning for at least 2 second before refreshing the layers myself. How can I do the same for the `dynamicMapLayer`, can I pause or stop the automatic refresh and decide myself when I want the export request to be made?

Note that we cannot use tiles for better performance, because of other reasons the layer must stay dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I prevent a `dynamicMapLayer` from refreshing on every zoom or pan of the map?

You can not. [It is designed that way](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/blob/3f0af3c5331be2f086270c4953afebcc56af792a/src/Layers/RasterLayer.js#L37).

Unless the esri folks redesign that to make a subclass of `L.GridLayer` instead of `L.ImageOverlay`, there's hardly any way around it.

> I'm already controlling the refresh by making sure the user has stopped zooming or panning for at least 2 second before refreshing the layers myself. How can I do the same for the `dynamicMapLayer`?

With a horrible, ugly hack. Overwrite the private `L.Esri.DynamicMapLayer._update` method so that it becomes a decorator over the previous method, e.g. something like:

```
(function() {
  var previousProto = L.Esri.DynamicMapLayer.prototype;
  L.Esri.DynamicMapLayer.include({
    _update: function(){
       throttle(previousProto._update, 2000);
    }
  });
})();
```

It's ugly, it's against most good coding practices (overwriting private methods, eeeew), and it might break.

> Note that we cannot use tiles for better performance, because of other reasons the layer must stay dynamic.

I disagree. "tiles" doesn't mean "static". You can easily apply cache-busting, or use a [time dimension](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#time--elevation), or [send all data to the client and let it slice it into vector tiles for quick rendering](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid), or use something fancier like [Carto(DB)'s Torque](https://carto.com/torque/).

The fact that your Esri tools don't allow you to readily create different sets of tiles, or do not allow for tiled access of changing resources, or do not allow for triggering client-side data invalidations, doesn't mean that it cannot be accomplished.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. What about removing the dynamicMapLayer on zoomStart or dragStart, and then re-adding it myself after 2 seconds. Just tried this and it seems to work. It's ugly as well... but it seems to work. For the tiles, there's an attribute that will be used as a filter to control what lines are visible or not. There already 3 possibles values for this parameter and might be more in the future. The client prefers to keep using dynamicLayers and instead we plan to use simplified geometries at higher zoom levels to improve performance. Probably using the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

Comment: In your case, I'd make several sets of transparent tiles, and add/remove them to the map as appropriate. Delegate the features-at-clicked-point features as needed. Even use VectorGrid. I find clients forcing a technological question is (a lot of times) the wrong way.

Comment: Funny you should say that, just finished a long email thread with the client and I think she's finally willing to compromise on using tiles... Couldn't be happier, I wasted so much time trying to optimize the map using a dynamicLayer the last few days. She just didn't get the huge performance implications of going dynamic and wasn't willing to compromise on features.  Even after I showed her a proto using tiles and how fast it was, she didn't want to budge. Anyway, yeah, I'll be using transparent tiles, probably PNG8, one set per attribute value. Phew.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-D